# Less than comparison of template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class implementing red black tree that would behave kind of like a (pseudo)map. Pseudo-map because it would not store keys, only values, with keys being embedded in the values. It would require operator== and operator< overloads to test stored values against an arbitrary key and againts each other (using embedded key). E.g.

```
struct Val
{
    //some actual data
    std::string key;

    bool operator==(const Val &val) { return this->key == val.key; }
    bool opeartor==(const std::string &str) { return this->key == str; }
    bool opeartor<(const Val &val) { return this->key < val.key; }
    bool opeartor<(const std::string &str) { return this->key < str; }
};
```

This kind of "value" would go into this templated class:

```
template<typename T>
class Map
{
    struct Node
    {
        //...
        T data;
    };
    public:
        //..
        template<typename K> T value(const K &key) const
        {
            Node *it;
            //...
            if(it->data == key)
            //...

            int dir = (it->data < key);
            //...
        }
};
```

However while the line `if(it->data == key)` checks out fine (I am not using the class yet) the second one `int dir = (it->data < key);` does not with error "parse error in template argument list". Strangely if I change the comparison to `<=` it compiles fine. However at that point I already know it is not equal (the first check so `<` would do.

How do I fix it and why is it complaining about one operator and not the others?

Comment: Without the syntax errors, it compiles fine for me.

Comment: Might be https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10200. Do you have a template called `data` somewhere?

Comment: @T.C. Yes, wow! That is super-weird. Changed the name and it works. Could you please repost this as an answer? Thanks, this saved me a lot of futile attempts to solve it. No way I could figure this out on my own. Bug in compiler, hm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T.C. has posted the answer in the comments so I will just repeat it as an answer. The behaviour is due to long-standing bug in GCC https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10200 that manifests itself when one is not very creative with naming and has bunch of the same names in the class (in this case member variable named `data` in the nested class and the member method called `data` in the super-class).